# Named pipes between Java and C/C++ programs

Tags: java, c++, c, networking, connection

I think of using in windows a named pipe to communicate between two apps written in Java and C. Normally i use socket connection to do this, but now i have to cancel this idea and find a new solution.

I read that named pipe in java can be visible only inside JVM-is this true? 
Is there a way to establish named pipe between two apps wriiten in different language?

If not, what kind of technology do You advice?

Answer (score 3):

In order to *create* a Windows named pipe in Java, you'd have to resort to using JNI to call the native WINAPI functions.

You can create the named pipe in C++, though, and consume it in Java by opening it as a file in the pipe namespace after it has been created.

Answer (score 2):

Named pipes are much harder to get right than using sockets. Conceptually they are simpler.  However making them reliable and reasonably fault tolerant is much harder than for sockets.

I would suggest you reconsider sockets, this is designed for communication between processes.  Can you clarify why you cannot use sockets?  The reason I ask is that named pipes actually used sockets over loopback in reality.

A named pipe is an OS construct.  You can create the named pipe in your OS and then it can be accessed as if it were a file by Java and C, or any other program.  Communication between processes via file is very difficult to get right (if not impossible)  For example, you will have no idea that when you write to the named pipe, that anything is reading it unless you design your own flow control protocol. (Very difficult to test in all cases)

You may have heard of PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream and these classes can only be used in the same process (making them pretty useless)

EDIT: If you want an independant view of the most common and possibly the most sensible way to send data I suggest you try google.

```
java sockets - 2,210,000 hits
java named pipes - 90,000 hits
```

So perhaps sockets is 25x more sensible than named pipes. (and more supportable as there more tutorials and people who have experience with them)

Comment: My boss said I can't use sockets so I can't:) The true is that I wrote the Java part and my friend from work do C/++/Delphi part. His boss said that sockets are harder to implement and forced me to think about something else...so for now i choose namedpipes.

Comment: You wrote that implementation of named pipes are simple but make it stable is hard...hmm In my project there is very simple structure of data exchaned: One string in and one answer out and thats all. Do You still think it will be difficult to do this stable? Thx for replay:)

Comment: Your boss said you can't use sockets? Why? What is his budget for your learning curve on the alternatives? What is his risk mitigation in case it doesn't work? Or in case you can't make it work in time? What is the business requirement that maps to the prohibition on using sockets?

Comment: @Lucjan, perhaps your boss can clarify what it is that sockets are "harder to implement" than. If he has an easier solution, he should tell you what it is. btw named pipes is not it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply start an external process in Java and connect to it's pipes.

```
    // Execute command
    String command = "ls";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

    // Get pipes from process
    InputStream in = child.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = child.getOutputStream();
    InputStream error = child.getErrorStream();
```

Comment: although i find your proposed solution quite usable, what you are describing are not named pipes. named pipes have to be addressable from the outside (in case of *nix systems through the file system).