# what is pros and cons of using Socket for IPC between java and c++?

Tags: java, c++, ipc

I recently forced to find an IPC protocol that is best for communicate between java and c++.

I searched the SO for finding best protocol for this, I found socket is the best approach for this, in SO. But I couldn't find any thing about its cons or pros of sockets! So I want to know pros of this protocol and also I want to know pros of other protocol vs socket to choose best protocol for my application.

It is very likely that my two applications running on a same machine.

**Update** I should first select my protocol then I can decide run it on which system configuration.

Comment: What are the other options that you considered?

Comment: may be messaging or even using a file!

Comment: I hope you meant "messaging", not "massaging", right?

Comment: Your alternative options do not have any advantages over sockets in terms of simplifying your life: in all cases, you will end up writing a binary protocol, the difference will be in its delivery mechanism (files, messages, or sockets). If your alternative was, say, RMI, it would be a different story; but currently you are choosing among equally hard options, so I'd go with sockets simply for their ease of use and ubiquity.

Comment: Namedpipes another option but this SO question advices against in favor of sockets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112480/named-pipes-between-java-and-c-c-programs

Comment: I assume with socket you mean TCP? TCP is reasonably simple, well supported, highly optimized on modern OSes and available on almost anything. Really not much contest here imo. Also, you're probably interested in [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) for the actual message encoding.

Comment: Tnx for your help I know sockets is better than file system in a typical system!But all the thing I know from system that my applications must work on them is what I said in the question!Everything about system is in hand of our hardware team and our system maybe be an embedded system that doen't have a network card and ... so I can't use Sockets!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best IPC method really depends on what type of communication you have: Message passing, ensuring mutual exclusive execution, sharing data are various IPC, but sockets isn't the solution for all 3.

Think about, or provide information what form the information has you want to pass between the applications. Perhaps you find a typical scenario (like producer-consumer problem).

If you have a message-passing problem, comparable in principle to oldschool TCP services, sockets are a good idea because they are well-tested and easy to debug; They provide full decoupling, yet running locally doesn't have drawbacks compared to pipes because the kernel can do the blocking of one application (sender or receiver) efficiently.

Sockets can be UDP, TCP or Unix sockets. In any case you don't need a network card for local IPC with sockets.