# How do I write to the input stream of an already running java program?

Tags: java, php, linux

I have a CentOS server which is currently running a java jar application. I need  to write a php script to communicate with this running program via its input stream.  The java program outputs its output to a log file so I don't need access to the output stream.

I don't want to restart the program,  just access the running process and interact with it.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Search for **named pipes** (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=372505)

Comment: Or consider a loopback socket connection - see Peter Lawrey's answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112480/named-pipes-between-java-and-c-c-programs).

Comment: I went with a loopback socket connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If portability is not a big matter for you, why not creating your own pipe(s)? I don't know much about the java application but have a look at the "mkfifo" function/command.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the ProcessID of the application. You may do it using:

```
ps -Af | grep java
```

Since you are using java, you may feel more convenient with the `jps` command for finding the PID.

I'll assume PID of the running application is 12345. It suffices to issue the command:

```
cat >/proc/12345/fd/0
```

And whatever you type in will be put in the standard input of that application. Note that `fd` contains the file descriptors used by the application, and I suppose the 0-th file descriptor would always be `stdin`.

Using PHP for writing into the file (and thus being consumed by the application as input) is possible as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that only works if stdin happens to be a pty device. If it's a regular file, then you just overwrote that file. If it's /dev/null, then I suspect nothing will happen.

Comment: `cat` gives me "Text file busy".